# Basic Java/Android class templates ( <?> )

Tags: java, android, class-template

I know this is a very basic question, but I haven't been able to find a way to word it to find the answer either here or through Google.

In the following code:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

What does the <'?> mean for the adapter view class template? My guess is that it means the parameter can be an AdapterView holding any type, but I'm not sure and figured I'd ask the community.

Thanks

Comment: This handy [link](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) is pretty well-written and goes through all of the basics of Generics & their uses/limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The `parent` parameter can be an `AdapterView` that is an `AdapterView` for any other object type.

If you want to learn more, check out info on Generics.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize they were called generics in java so that will help me find out more about them.